# Can we execute a query string in BigQuery like we do in standard SQL using EXEC?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am forming a dynamic query using stored procedure based on input parameters and I want to execute the query string I formed in BigQuery.

Comment: As far as I know, you need to do this through an API not through the GUI.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Store procedures are not available in BigQuery (BQ), but if you want to manage input parameters, you can use [BQ parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries). Can you provide an example of the desired query and the expected output?

Comment: As of 5/20/2020, BigQuery released dynamic SQL feature for you to achieve the goal.

Dynamic SQL is now available as a beta release in all BigQuery regions. Dynamic SQL lets you generate and execute SQL statements dynamically at runtime. For more information, see [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate).